# Firefox 50 crashes after TestCleanup method is called using WebDriver 3.0.1

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm learnign `Selenium WebDriver` with `C#`.

I have wrote a simple test program:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    IWebDriver driver;
    [TestMethod]
    public void VerifyTitle()
    {
        //Write Actual Test
        string title = driver.Title;
        Assert.AreEqual(title, "Demoqa | Just another WordPress site");
    }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        //start browser and oprn url

        FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(@"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe");
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http:/www.demoqa.com");
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void CleanupTest()
    {
        //close browser
        driver.Quit();
    }
```

Everything is fine and test is passed.
However, my browser crashes after `driver.Quit()`is called:

[image]

Comment: I've got exactly the same issue. I guess we're not the only ones with this issue, someone made a bug-report that looks awfully similar, it's a shame it got locked: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/173

Comment: Which version of windows are you using??

Answer (score 0):

I have been getting the same issue so I worked around it by declaring the driver as a None type.

```
mydriver = webdriver.Firefox()`
mydriver.get('url')
##DO STUFF

mydriver = None
```

Assigning it to None, closes the browser and all of its operations, Although it's an easy work around I would not consider this a proper solution. Anyways, hope this helps!

If your still having issues, I recommend you download the [Chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/), which is much more stable with selenium in my opinion.